# Can't figure out why my image in my website wont cover the whole screen

Tags: html, css

I just made a div in my css file and I use it in the body of my html.

```
.fixed-bg {
  height: 100%;
  left: -10px;
  background-image: url("space.png");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

This is the div.

It results in an image that almost covers the entire screen, it just leaves a 5px~ gap in all sides and I want to make it so that there is no gap. There is no nesting and that is the only div that effects this part of the html at all I just can't figure out how to get rid of the gap. If it helps I am using flask as my framework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to the `body`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: `body` has no default `padding`, so `margin: 0` will suffice.